# Header(Bold text) and body in iOS Push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, formatting, apple-push-notifications

I want to know how exactly do we include bold text in iOS push notifications. I have attached a sample image below.

[image]

Just like **Time for bed** i want to trigger push notification with bold text for title and normal text for body like "Stay consistent: Go to bed in 15 minutes"

I see many other apps also do it.

Answer (score 5):

From:
[bold (or other formatting) in iOS push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647061/bold-or-other-formatting-in-ios-push-notification)

There is no rich text functionality in iOS Push Notifications.

An alternative for iOS 8.2 plus may be to use the 'title' to display the sender's name, and place the new message in the body. For example, try a payload such as this:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Jim",
            "body": "Hey bob"
        },
        "badge": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Saw the answer in some other question and gave it a try. Did not work though. Is there any other settings or params that has to be included other than this?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it by sending a silent push message and then trigger a local notification in your app. The code for the latter part looks as follows:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Bold title"
content.body = "regular text"
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
let center = UNNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(request)
```